# how to add or remove classes using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, class, svg, event-handling, use-ref

```
   const ref = useRef(null)
  const handleClick = () => {
  if(ref.current.classList.contains('hidden')){
    ref.current.classList.remove('hidden')
  }else{
    ref.current.classList.add('hidden')
  }
 }
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList')

```
             <div className='px-4 cursor-pointer md:hidden' id='burger' onClick={handleClick()}>
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
          </svg>
          </div>
          <ul className='text-sm mt-6 hidden md:block' id='menu' ref={ref}>
```

> I am using tailwindcss in ReactJS

Answer (score 0):

In your jsx, it should be `onClick={handleClick}`. You need to pass the function reference without invoking it

Answer (score 0):

```js
import './App.css';

export default function App() {
  const handleClick = event => {
    // ️ toggle class on click
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('bg-salmon');

    // ️ add class on click
    // event.currentTarget.classList.add('bg-salmon');

    // ️ remove class on click
    // event.currentTarget.classList.remove('bg-salmon');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but I found another answer that is easier using useState()

Answer (score 0):

```
     const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(true)
return(
         <div className='px-4 cursor-pointer md:hidden' id='burger' onClick={() => setHidden(prevStatus => !prevStatus)}>
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" strokeWidth={2}>
                    <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16" />
                  </svg>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <ul className={`text-sm mt-6 ${hidden ? '' : 'hidden' } md:block`} id='menu' >)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).